# Changing the SelectedItem event for ToggleButton in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, togglebutton

I have a [image: Simple TreeView]

XAML:

```
<StackPanel >
    <TextBlock Text="Simple TreeView with 3 level hierarchy" />
    <TreeView >
        <TreeViewItem Header='Heading 1'>
            <TreeViewItem Header='SubHeading 1.1'>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Leaf 1.1.1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Leaf 1.1.2"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header='SubHeading 1.2'>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Leaf 1.2.1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Leaf 1.2.2"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header='SubHeading 1.3'/>
            <TreeViewItem Header='SubHeading 1.4'/>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header='Heading 2'>
            <TreeViewItem Header='SubHeading 2.1'/>
            <TreeViewItem Header='SubHeading 2.2'/>
            <TreeViewItem Header='SubHeading 2.3'/>
            <TreeViewItem Header='SubHeading 2.4'/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

The current behavior

- Lets assume **SubHeading 1.2** is **currently selected** and its toggle button is expanded.
- If I click on the toggle button of **Heading 2**, it will get expanded but **SubHeading 1.2** is still going to be the currently selected item.
- But If I click on the toggle button of **Heading 1** to collapse, all its sub headings will be collapsed and **Heading 1** will become the Selected item.

Expected Behaviour

- Instead of **Heading 1** to be the currently selected item I would want to keep **SubHeading 1.2** as the selected item even though it is collapsed.

i.e. On such collapses of the parent node, it triggers SelectedItemChanged event updating the currently SelectedItem to the parent node. How to keep the SelectedItem intact with child node and not update it?

Comment: you could keep track of your selectedItem and change it programmatically